# highcharts column : add dynamically series with drilldown data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

my problem I have an highcharts graph type column with drilldown values and I want to add dynamically another series of data with drilldown values

can anyone help me with this problem ??

Comment: Please share used code. What have you already tried? Drilldown values should be in data, so if you add another series dynamically it should work fine - do you have any errors or problems? What's the data format? Please share an exemplary data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Make data in your back end language and convert into JSON then update chart either by using ajax or on page load.